Possible ways to structure a periodic table in JavaFX?
I am currently writing a JavaFX application for my programming class, and I decided to, among other things, make a periodic table. I already have a .txt file with a bunch of info (name, symbol, mass, etc.), and an fxml card to make each element card (which opens another window when clicked on) but im not sure how to structure the main application to resize properly with me moving the borders.
I am not sure exactly what to even try, since it just seems like an impossible task for me and my limited ability in JavaFX, since I have always struggled with programming in general.

I would consider using a GridPane as the table's layout.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

a periodic table with Gridpane layout
I made this as a mockup in scenebuilder
GridPane is a good choice for column and row order
fxml file is here


Would a Gist be better suited over Google Drive? I ask because in the past, I have seen Google Drive links not work at some point. As of today, I have never seen a bad Gist link on a post.

I tried to inline the massive FXML in case that was possible.  It was not ;-) -> "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 161930.".

I was curious how an app with such a large FXML would perform on a 2019 Intel MacBook Pro.  Loading the FXML took ~750 milliseconds and displaying a stage with the loaded scene took 450 milliseconds (vs 100 milliseconds for an empty stage).  Overall, displaying the table loaded from FXML using this method took about an additional 1.1 seconds over displaying an empty stage.

Sorry , I tried to reduce it ,but  I couldn't ( I reach just 70000 chars ) . I think is useless as code , but  helpful as an idea  : sorry I 'm not  a prefessional and I don't use github I am fraid  of spread bad code

Based on your description, I believe you get the details of each element from the text file and build a node from the fxml template(for card) and you want to build the table.
As others suggested GridPane will be the best option in this case. I suggest you provide all the details in the text file, like the element row number, column number, color code, etc etc. That way you can have flexibility in placing the elements and styling.
Below is a quick demo of what I believe is close to your requirement. You can consider this for some initial ideas of how you can start.

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class PeriodicTableDemo extends Application {
    // ROW_NO, COL_NO, ELE_NUM, ELE_NAME, COLOR_CODE
    String text = """
            0,0,1,A,#01F300
            0,6,2,B,#00BDFA
            1,0,3,C,#FAA600
            1,1,4,D,#FEFE02
            1,5,5,E,#7FFFD3
            1,6,6,F,#00BDFA
            2,0,7,G,#FAA600
            2,1,8,H,#FEFE02
            2,2,9,I,#FFC0CB
            2,3,10,J,#FFC0CB
            2,4,11,K,#FFC0CB
            2,5,12,L,#7FFFD3
            2,6,13,M,#00BDFA
            3,0,14,N,#FAA600
            3,1,15,O,#FEFE02
            3,2,16,P,#FFC0CB
            3,3,17,Q,#FFC0CB
            3,4,18,R,#FFC0CB
            3,5,19,S,#7FFFD3
            3,6,20,T,#00BDFA
            """;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        String cardStyle = "-fx-border-width:1px;-fx-border-color:black;-fx-border-radius:5px;-fx-background-radius:5px;-fx-background-color:";
        String[] arr = text.split("\n");

        // Create a grid pane
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(5);
        grid.setVgap(5);

        // Decide how many total rows and cols to add constraints
        int totalRows = 0;
        int totalCols = 0;

        // Loop each element and fetch the details
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            String[] vals = arr[i].split(",");
            int rowIndex = Integer.parseInt(vals[0]);
            int colIndex = Integer.parseInt(vals[1]);
            totalRows = rowIndex > totalRows ? rowIndex : totalRows;
            totalCols = colIndex > totalCols ? colIndex : totalCols;

            // Load the fxml card and set the details to the nodes
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("element_card.fxml"));
            try {
                // Load fxml and get the controller and root node
                StackPane card = fxmlLoader.load();
                ElementCardController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();

                // Sets the position in the grid
                GridPane.setRowIndex(card, rowIndex);
                GridPane.setColumnIndex(card, colIndex);

                // Updates the nodes in the card
                controller.setElementNumber(vals[2]);
                controller.setElementName(vals[3]);

                // Update the card style
                card.setStyle(cardStyle + vals[4]);

                // Finally add the card to the grid
                grid.getChildren().add(card);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        final RowConstraints rowConstraint = new RowConstraints();
        rowConstraint.setFillHeight(true);
        rowConstraint.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

        final ColumnConstraints columnConstraint = new ColumnConstraints();
        columnConstraint.setFillWidth(true);
        columnConstraint.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

        // Add constraints to total rows and columns to let the cells fit when resizing
        IntStream.rangeClosed(0, totalRows).forEach(r -> grid.getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraint));
        IntStream.rangeClosed(0, totalCols).forEach(c -> grid.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraint));

        StackPane root = new StackPane(grid);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("PeriodicTable Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

element_card.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ElementCardController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="elementNumber" text="" style="-fx-font-size:12px;" StackPane.alignment="TOP_LEFT"/>
        <Label fx:id="elementName" text="" style="-fx-font-size:14px;-fx-font-weight:bold;"/>
    </children>
    <padding>
        <Insets topRightBottomLeft="8"/>
    </padding>
</StackPane>

ElementCardController.java
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class ElementCardController {
    @FXML
    private Label elementNumber;

    @FXML
    private Label elementName;

    public void setElementName(String name) {
        elementName.setText(name);
    }

    public void setElementNumber(String name) {
        elementNumber.setText(name);
    }
}

